# What is the range for keywordstats?

Tags: facebook-ads-api, keywordstats

What is the time range for the data returned by the Ads API keywordstats method? Is it simply the sum of the last 7 days?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says, that it's for the last 7 days, not including the current day.

Comment: Does Facebook convert the stats to the ad account's local timezone like it does for other methods?